IBM cognos 11.02 Formula to calculate the Grand Total
I created the following formula to sum the Invoice amount based on a distinct Invoice statement number But I am not getting the Grand total at the bottom for the subtotals above.
I created this formula
total (distinct [Pre-tax Amount] FOR  [Invoice Statement Number])


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Are you trying to do this on a report page?  ...in a dashboard?   Or is this really a query question?  How about a screen capture?
